# Generic type lost when using a nested interface

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble using generics with 'nested' interfaces and `ReadonlyArray`. How can I run the `filterList` function without losing the type for the `list` parameter?

```
interface INumber {
    value: number
}

interface IState {
    readonly numbers: ReadonlyArray<INumber>
}

var state: IState = {
    numbers: [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 4 }]
} 

function filterList<T>(list: T) {
    return list.filter(x => x.value > 2);
}

// Error: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'T'.
const res = filterList(state.numbers);
```

Changing the `filterList` function to the below will fail due to using ReadonlyArray.

```
function filterList(list: INumber[]) {...}

// Error: Argument of type 'ReadonlyArray<INumber>' is not assignable
// to parameter of type 'INumber[]'. Property 'pop' is missing in 
// type 'ReadonlyArray<INumber>'.
const res = filterList(state.numbers);
```

Whats the best practice for handling this situation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several choices. `ReadonlyArray<T>` si a subset of `Array`, so we can constain `T` to be a `ReadonlyArray` of something that has a value:

```
var state: IState = {
  numbers: [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 4 }]
} 

function filterList<T extends ReadonlyArray<{value : number }>>(list: T){
  return list.filter(x => x.value > 2);
}

const res = filterList(state.numbers); // ok

var arr = [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 4 }]
const res2 = filterList(arr); //ok
```

Although you don't get much out of having the type parameter being the list, as `filter` will return a regular array for both `ReadonlyArray` and `Array`, so this will work as well:

```
function filterList<T extends {value : number }>(list: ReadonlyArray<T>){
  return list.filter(x => x.value > 2);
}
const res = filterList(state.numbers); // ok

var arr = [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 4 }]
const res2 = filterList(arr); //ok
```

If you want `filterList` to preserve whether a readonly array or a regular array was passed in, you can use the first version and return `T`, but you will need to use a type assertion to make the result of `filter` pe typed as a `ReadonlyArray`

```
function filterList<T extends ReadonlyArray<{value : number }>>(list: T): T{
  return list.filter(x => x.value > 2) as any;
}

const res = filterList(state.numbers); // ok, res is ReadonlyArray<INumber>

var arr = [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 4 }]
const res2 = filterList(arr); //ok, res s { value: number; }[]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.